# When to make kiddush at a Seder with no wine?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, grapes-wine, kiddush

What is one supposed to do on Seder night if he has no wine (nor *chamar medinah* if that’s relevant) at all?

On a regular Friday night one would make *kiddush* on bread under these circumstances (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayyim 272:9) but on Seder night one is supposed to eat *karpas* and say the *haggadah* before eating *matzah*.

So what does one do? Make kiddush on *matzah* right at the start of the *seder*? Defer *kiddush* until after *maggid*? Some other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shulchan Arukh OC 483

> מי שאין לו יין בליל פסח מקדש על הפת שמברך המוציא ובוצע ומניח ידיו עליו עד שגומר הקידוש ומברך על אכילת מצה ואוכל ואחר כך אוכל שאר ירקות ומסלק השלחן ואומר מה נשתנה וכל ההגדה עד גאל ישראל ומברך על המרור ואוכל ואחר כך כורך מצה ומרור ואוכל.
>
> One who doesn't have wine on Pesach night [takes the Matza, says Hamotzi, splits it, says Kiddush on it] and blesses על אכילת מצה and eats it and then eats [Karpas] and then removes the table and says [Maggid] and then [Maror] and then [Korekh]

Comment: That's Rochtza Motzi Yachatz Kaddesh Matza Karpas Maggid Urchatz Maror Korekh Shulchan-Orekh Tzafun Barekh Hallel

Comment: Although note Magen Avraham that for those with the practice of using three matzot, Yachatz should precede Motzi.

Comment: @Joel yes, though the Magen Avraham isn't so compelling because why would the Rif have insisted you keep two full ones for Hamotzi if he doesn't need Lechem Mishneh? there are also a handful of other options in rishonim for how to order things.

Comment: I think Rif means you start with one and a half, make hamotzi, break the half further and then say kiddush and al achilat matzah. See Bach and Pri Megadim

Comment: @JoelK if so then those who use two and half would still break the half further after motzi, since when you break the half further is not tied to the 1.5/2.5 dispute

Comment: Rif holds hamotzi is on the half, so makes sense to break it as soon as possible after hamotzi. MA is assuming that hamotzi is on both the whole and the half (as recommended by SA) and you can’t break them until the end because you need lechem mishneh for kiddush